# Centering images in html using tex4ht

Tags: floats, tex4ht, html

I am trying to convert latex doxument in html using `tex4ht`and to get centered image. I am inspired by the code in the post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474263/on-centering-image-on-a-web-page-using-tex4ht-is-this-the-correct-way) I use the following `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book} \usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\newtheorem{exemple}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newcommand\inputpstex[1]{\input{#1.pstex_t}}
\newcommand{\myTexFigure}[2]{
      \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \inputpstex {#1}
    \caption{#2}\label{f:#1}
    \end{figure}
      \vspace{3mm}
      }
\title{Test}
\author{S.~Oulhoussine}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Calcul}
Ceci est un test
\begin{exemple}[Pendule simple]
figure d'un pendule
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{pendule.ps}\\
  \caption{Image d'un pendule}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}\label{linvar:e}
5 \cos (t) \frac{{dy(t)}}{{dt}}+ 3  y(t) = 10 u(t)
\end{equation}
\end{exemple}
L'exemple est déjà fini.
\end{document}
```

I converted using the command line

```
make4ht -c my.cfg test.tex
```

with the the following configuration file `my.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\Css{div.figure img {text-align:center;display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Here are the pendule.ps and [pendule.pstex_t](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ft-OVT5BdVvSaOsbbD_faxcWM9ykDebv) files.
I get this html file
[image]
As you can see, the html figure is not centerd. Can you help please ?

Comment: It seems the link to the `pendule.ps` file is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS code in your config file is correct, it just conflicts with one CSS declaration in TeX4ht sources:

```
 \Css{.figure img.graphics {margin-left:10\%;}}
```

This sets left margin of the image to 10% of the page width. I don't really know why it is there, it seems like a really old declaration that is not useful anymore. So I will remove it from the sources. To fix it at the moment, you can override it using CSS declaration that will have higher specificity than the declaration above:

```
 \Css{figure.figure img.graphics {text-align:center;display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;}}
```

This is the result with a different image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks michal.h21

Comment: I tested it and it worked very well. thank you again.